# Dice coefficient with threshold

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

---

Set threshold for my dice coefficient metric, but it seems not working correctly.

```
y_true and y_pred have values between 0 and 1.  I am using a Unet in Keras.
```

```
    def dice_coef_NoHand(self,y_true, y_pred,smooth=1):
    # greater = tf.keras.backend.greater(y_pred, 0.5000)
    # y_pred = tf.where(y_pred>0.5, y_pred, [0.0])

    # #y_pred_2 = K.cast(K.greater(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1), 0.9), K.floatx())
    #
    # y_true = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(y_true)
    # y_pred_flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(y_pred)
    # y_pred = tf.round(y_pred_flatten)
    # intersection = tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred)
    # return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.reduce_sum(y_true) + tf.reduce_sum(y_pred) + smooth)
    cond = y_pred > 0.5
    y_pred_new = tf.where(cond, y_pred, 0.0)
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred_new)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
```

All elements smaller than 0.5 should become 0 in y_pred. To check if this works with the above given function, I have the following metric, which I log during the training:

```
        def y_pred_max(self,y_true,y_pred):

        cond = y_pred > 0.5
        y_pred = tf.where(cond, y_pred, 0.0)
        y_pred_max = tf.maximum(y_pred, y_true)

        return y_pred_max
```

Now I should not get values between 0 and 0.5 for y_pred_max. But I am still getting values such as 0.04,...

How can I implement a threshold for my dice coefficient?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you replace your images of code with the actual code? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72195156/correct-implementation-of-dice-loss-in-tensorflow-keras

Comment: @vijayachandranmariappan thanks! The aspect with the adjustment of the smooth value is very interesting. As I have images where the ground truth has no white pixels at all and exactly for these images I get good predictions but still a very low dice coefficient (used as a metric). Maybe I should adjust this. However, I don't understand how I get values between 0 and 0.5 for y_pred_max when I have set a threshold before..

Comment: In `tf.maximum(y_pred, y_true)`, when your y_pred is zero, then `y_pread_max` will be y_true, which can be < 0.5?

Comment: y_true only as zeros. If I used like this tf.maximum(y_pred, 0.0) ist doesnt work either.